# Compute the sum of the following series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \left(e^{-jx}\right)\left(x^j\right) $$for $x$ on $[0, \infty)$.

I already proved that this series converges uniformly for $x$ on $[0, \infty)$, i.e. its partial sum converges uniformly to a function on $[0, \infty)$. But I just could not get a fair guess of what that limiting function is, or how to compute it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hint: Geometric series.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an infinite series: 
$1 + \left(e^{-x}x\right) + (e^{-x}x)^2 + (e^{-x}x)^3 + \cdots = (1- e^{-x}x)^{-1}$